# PHP fOpen unsure where folders must be to be able to open them

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

Hi i am trying to create a web page that asks the user for two words then will replace the first word with the second word in a file. I have an html file that is working fine. I have a working ubuntu server 16.04 that i am running my html on.

The problem comes in when i try to use PHP to open a file but i am unsure if the file must be on my host desktop or on my virtual machine which i am unsure about.

My html code

```
<html>
   <body>
    <form action="replace.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">>

    <table border="0">

    <tr>
            <td>Old String</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Old_string" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td>New String</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="New_string" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <input type="submit" value="Change Values" name="submit">
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td> Select File that will be changed:</td>
        <input type="file" name="FiletoChange" id="FiletoChange">
    </tr>



    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

My PHP code

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Information Gathered</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
        $valid = true;
        if (!empty($_POST["Old_string"])) {
            $Old_string = $_POST["Old_string"];
        } else {
            $valid = false;
            echo "Old string is Empty . Please Enter value to proceed";
        }
        if (!empty($_POST["New_string"])) {
            $New_string = $_POST["New_string"];
        } else {
            $valid = false;
            echo "New string is Empty . Please Enter value to proceed";
        }
        if ($valid) {
            echo "all input correct";
        }

        //$myfile = fopen("C:\\Users\\ipadc\\Pictures\\pappa\\EXpert system taak.txt", "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
        //echo fread($myfile,filesize("C:\\Users\\ipadc\\Pictures\\pappa\\EXpert system taak.txt"));
        //fclose($myfile);
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

I have commented out my Open file code in the PHP cause i am not sure where this folder must be located for me to be able to access it. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your web server? The file would proabaly best be placed on that as that is where the PHP scripts run

Comment: My web server is being run within virtualbox

Comment: Then thats where the file shoudl be

Comment: But i am unsure how to reference the files cause i tried referencing a file on my virtual machine but it simply said folder not found

Comment: I am quite new to linux so where in the directory would be the best place to put a textfile? i do not have a interface to work with so i am a bit confused with all the directories

Comment: The file will be on the virtual machine. The web server user will have limited permissions. The user is not the same user as witch you login with. Are you putting your script in /var/www/html/ ot /home/your loginPublic/ ?

Comment: /var/www/html/  is where my scripts are

Comment: Ok if i place the txt file in the  /var/www/html/  file then it finds it but it then says permission denied

Comment: On the file you name do chmod a+rw <your text file>

Comment: Thank you @JasonK works 100% now

Comment: On a real server you would not have any file writable from with in the web directory.